# Searchbar not visible on top of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have dragged a searchbar on top of my tableview (tableview has cells loaded on it). The `searchBarDelegate` has also been set. But when I run the project, the searchbar is not visible on top. Just the space occupied by it is left blank.

Did I miss anything...?

These lines of code were added. But I don't think they play a part in the searchbar not showing...

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText != "" {
        searchActive = true;
    }
}
```

Also in `viewDidLoad` this is given...

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

Comment: share your screenshot of your view

Comment: First drag and drop SearchBar on you view then after adding table view on the view

Comment: @iPatel you mean first the searchbar should be added and then the tableview...?

Comment: @bvt yes go this way

Comment: It doesn't work that way, @iPatel..

Comment: How you are adding ? is it possible to put screenshot of your storyboard here ?

Comment: Thanks @iPatel..But its working now. Had kept the search bar at the extreme top. But had to keep it some distance down...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160324/discussion-between-ipatel-and-bvt).